# How to create a relation chain from LinkedHashMap entries?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

```
Map<String, List<String>> parentChildMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

has the below contents:

```
{"a": ["a1", "a2", "a3"]}
{"a2": ["a21", "a22"]}
{"a22": []}
```

I want to create the following strings:

1. a -> a1
2. a -> a2 -> a21
3. a -> a2 -> a22
4. a -> a3

I guess I could recursively assemble them, but I don't know how to write the recursive function. (Iteratively would also be fine.)

Comment: Why `a -> a` ? If it is a parent-child relationship as the name indicates, why is `a` pointing at itself?

Comment: @Eritrean, Yes, truely , I will remove this case.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do exactly. What do you mean by "assemble them"?

Answer (score 0):

You can list all the chains starting with one string using the following methods:

```
public void listChains(String start, Consumer<List<String>> cons) {
    listChains(start, new ArrayList<>(), cons);
}

private void listChains(String start, List<String> chain,
        Consumer<List<String>> cons) {
    int n = chain.size();
    chain.add(start);
    List<String> children = parentChildMap.get(start);
    if (children == null || children.isEmpty()) {
        cons.accept(chain);
    } else {
        children.forEach(child -> {
            listChains(child, chain, cons);
        });
    }
    chain.remove(n);
}
```

To print all chains starting from "a", you would do:

```
listChains("a", (chain) -> {
    System.out.println(chain.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" -> ")));
});
```